# An impressive combinatorial identity

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm trying to show that, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall p\in\mathbb{N^*},$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{4^k}{2k-1}{2k\choose k}\frac{\displaystyle{n+k-1\choose n-k+1}{2(n+p-k)\choose n+p-k}}{\displaystyle{n+p\choose k}}\right)=\frac{8}{p}{2(p-1)\choose p-1}\frac{\displaystyle{2(2n+p)\choose2n+p}}{\displaystyle{2n+2p\choose2n+p}}$$
I have checked numerically, I'm confident it's true. But I have absolutely no idea as of how to even start to prove this.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Unless you're a reincarnation of Ramanujan, you probably didn't come up with this out of thin air. If you tell us how this arose, that might conceivably help us prove it?

Comment: Probably easiest way to prove this identity is the following: <br/>

1- Firstly, note that you can change the bounds of the summation to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ <br/>

2-  In your formula divide both sides with the right hand side. Then, we have a sum of the form $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}SOMETHING$. It is enough to show that $f(n)$ satisfies the recurrence $f(n+1)-f(n)=0$ , i.e $f(n)$ is a constant and $f(0)=1$, i.e this constant is 1.  <br/>

3- Applying creative telescoping algorithm to $f(n)$ gives $N-1$ meaning that $f(n)$ satisfies $f(n+1)-f(n)=0$ and $f(0)=1$. Thus, you are done:)

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a picture of maple output as well:

[image]

In the output, $N-1$ is the annihilating operator of the sum where $N$ is the shift operator with respect to $n$. The other part of the output is not important for the sake of this question.